# Remote command-line access to a Windows machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-access

I normally access my hosted dedicated server, running Windows Server 2k3, via Remote Desktop. However, that service is bizarrely unavailable today and so I urgently need an alternative method for accessing that box, in particular for copying in a file that is needed. I can ftp into it but that doesn't give me access to the directory I need.

Is there a command-line utility I can use to get a shell on that machine? I have the necessary credentials.

Edit: I should clarify that I do not have domain access to this machine; I only have Internet access.

Answer (score 1):

possibly
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Comment: Does PsExec work for machines that I only have Internet access to?

Comment: if you have admin on the remote server and there are no firewalls and like John Gardeniers pointed out no AV software to block the execution, then maybe!  I personally don't think you'll have any luck since they probably will have block all the relevant ports. try this telnet servername 135 to see if there is a firewall in the way

Comment: Failed on both port 135 and port 23. Looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: figures, wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

Try SSH through KpyM ssh server and putty. All Macs and many Linux distros support SSH right out of the box. You can also use Teamviewer or TightVNC as an alternative to Remote Desktop.

You can also use Wol to wake your server after you shut it down or it goes into sleep. I use all of these methods to keep my home server alive and running. This might depend on your server host however.

Comment: Curious did you read the question? All of your 'alternatives' are something he 'could' do in the future but all require access to the server to setup.

Comment: Actually I did. He is not asking how to hack his own server though... He is outside the network as he stated in his comment. Thanks for the vote down :b *sarcasm*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download and install **eurysco** on the remote machine and use the command line feature...

http://www.eurysco.com/feature/command-line

Comment: Do you work for this vendor?

Comment: no, this is a free and open source software that I developed... it's based on PHP :)

Comment: Please see the ["Avoid overt self-promotion"](http://serverfault.com/help/behavior) section of the Help Center.  If you're only here to link your project, it may not be well received.

Comment: ok, but I wrote it in good faith and it does not seem to be out of topic... the next time I lie and say they have nothing to do with the software in question :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx), specifically PsExec, which lets open a remote command shell.

Also, this question should probably be on ServerFault..

Comment: Does PsExec work over the Internet? I do not have domain access to this machine.

Comment: It relies on the SMB ports, which are almost always blocked. If you're stuck outside of the local network, then there are two ways you can get a shell. You can either hack your own server, or you can have installed something in the past. Or ask the support guys, of course..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to spawn a copy of cmd.exe.  This of course assumes that the firewalls don't block this type of access and whatever is broken for RDP is not also breaking other things.

Comment: It's worth noting that nearly every antivirus software I've used also blocks psexec.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't help with your immediate problem but we install a Cygwin ssh deamon on our Windows servers for this. I suggest that you may have a firewall issue today, fix that then get a ssh server on the machine. It doesn't have to be Cygwin, there are commerial alternatives. Firewall people are much happier about keeping port 22 open for secure traffic.

Answer (score 0):

[`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) is the quick answer, but doesn't allow a session.

For a richer environment use [PowerShell Remoting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart/) (link to quick start from CTP timeframe, but should get you started).